# Adding Custom Documentation to Overridden Functions

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, comments, markdown

I've been trying to get into the habit of adding Apple's variant of Markdown documentation to all functions that I write. However, I'm unsure how to add this documentation to show up in quicklook windows. Is it possible to replace, or ideally append to existing documentation?

For example, in this picture, the quicklook window shows the existing Markdown documentation instead of the documentation that I've written above.

[image: Here's an example of what I'm referring to]

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there seems to be no way to do this.

You can define a new function with its own documentation that calls the overridden function and nothing else.

**Example:**

```
/**
 custom documentation
 */
func viewDidLoadOverridden() {
    viewDidLoad()
}
```

**Result:**

[image: custom documentation for "overridden" function]

Comment: Bummer, over a year and there’s still no good way of doing this. I think your idea is interesting, but a bit too much of a workaround for my liking (imagine trying to get a team of devs to agree to write functions like that as a workaround for documentation).